# How to Pivot the data by awk in unix shell script?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I'm trying to pivot a file using awk. This is an example of my input File:

```
P2P,P2P,MP,DL,AIR,UP,HR,UPE,GSM,S,PP,1,NA,0.2,0.2
P2P,P2P,MP,DL,AI,UP,HR,UPE,GSM,F,PP,4,NA,0.2,0.8
P2P,P2P,MP,DL,AIR,UP,HR,UPE,GSM,S,PP,1,NA,0.2,0.2
P2P,P2P,MP,DL,AI,UP,HR,UPE,GSM,S,PP,1,NA,0.2,0.2
P2P,P2P,MP,DL,AIR,UP,HR,UPE,GSM,S,PP,1,NA,0.2,0.2
P2P,P2P,MP,DL,AIR,UP,HR,UPE,GSM,F,PP,1,NA,0.2,0.2
P2P,P2P,MP,DL,BIR,UP,HR,UPE,GSM,S,PP,10,NA,0.2,2
P2P,P2P,MP,KT,AIR,UP,HR,UPE,GSM,S,PP,1,NA,0.2,0.2
P2P,P2P,MP,MM,AIR,UP,HR,UPE,GSM,S,PP,1,NA,0.2,0.2
```

Desired output should be following.

```
AIR,5,1  
AI,1,0.2  
BIR,10,2
```

- Here the first field belongs to `$5`.
- The Second field belogs to `$12` (total of `$12`).
- And the third field belongs to `$15` (total of `$15`).

Condition should be following in `awk`:

```
$3=="MP" && $10=="S" && $5!="MP"
```

Comment: I am not sure "pivot" is the word to use here. "Aggregate" is more apt. In my understanding, *to pivot* means to change columns and rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk for filtering and [GNU Datamash](http://www.gnu.org/s/datamash) for the pivoting you can do:

```
$ awk -F, '$3=="MP" && $10=="S" && $5!="MP"' FILE.TXT \
     | datamash --sort -t, --group 5 sum 12 sum 15
AI,1,0.2
AIR,5,1
BIR,10,2
```

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F, '$3=="MP"&&$10=="S"&&$5!="MP"{a[$5]+=$12;b[$5]+=$15}
  END{for(i in a){print i","a[i]","b[i]}}' file
```

---

- `-F,` sets the delimiter to `,`.
- `$3=="MP"&&$10=="S"&&$5!="MP"{...}` this is the condition from the question

  - `a[$5]+=$12;b[$5]+=$15` fills an array `a` with the total value of `$12` and an array `b` with the total value of `$15`.
- `END{...}` this block runs when `awk` has finished processing all lines.

  - `for(i in a)` loops trough the `a` array
  - `print i","a[i]","b[i]}` prints the values in the two arrays and its index.

---

The output:

```
AI,1,0.2
AIR,5,1
BIR,10,2
```

Comment: + add `OFS=","` and `print i, a[i], b[i]` will look better than `print i","a[i]","b[i]`

Comment: This does not maintain the order, though it is not clear if that is needed.

Comment: @joepd What kind of order would you expect?

Comment: @Costas: The one stated as "Desired outcome". Not sure how that would relate to the data, though, except order of first appearance. Will make things a bit more complicated.